# Reset count after grouping on crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am writing a report on Crystal Reports 2013. I'm doing multiple groupings on the report and basically, I want a field to be displayed on the first instance of the second group.

Below illustrates what I'm trying to do:

1. Group 1 a

   - Group 2 a

     - Display
   - Group 2 b

     - Not Display
   - Group 2 c

     - Not Display
2. Group 1 b

   - Group 2 a

     - Display
   - Group 2 b

     - Not Display
       etc…

Any ideas on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the suppresion-formula of the field
(Replace `{Table.FirstGroupCol}` with the column you used to group `Group1`:

```
Not (OnFirstRecord Or (Previous({Table.FirstGroupCol})<>{Table.FirstGroupCol}))
```

This will only display the field on the first record or if the previous value of the column used for Group 1 is different from the current one.